Why do I have a duplicate entry under network for my PC and how can I delete it?
Under Windows 10 Explorer I do have a double entry for my computer name (DELL-INSPIRON). One entry contains icons, the 2nd is completely empty. This I'd like to remove if possible.


That is a feature of Windows Explorer. There are duplicate drive letters and libraries, and they might appear because of multiple settings, such as display of Libraries and drives both under This PC and separately.
First thing to try is to turn off Show libraries in Explorer Folder Options.

There are various tutorials for removing that feature, such as at 11 Forums and The Windows Club. There are also free tools to make this easier, such as Ultimate Windows Tweaker

and Hidden Windows 10 Features.

If you want to do so manually using Regedit (which can be dangerous) according to Microsoft's directions:

Press Windows, type rege and select Regedit.

Enter HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders in the location bar (which may be copied and pasted from here) and delete the entry for {F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}.

Enter HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders in the location bar (which may be copied and pasted from here) and delete the entry for {F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}.



Thanks a lot, will check.
